# java wicket link onclick code does not execute on second click

Tags: java, hyperlink, onclick, wicket

I have created a fragment inside a page which contains a Dataview and inside it is a Link. The dataview contains the link which has the member's name and other columns with the member's info like the birthdate. The Link is supposed to show the information of the selected member using JasperSoft(PDF). The thing is on the first click it all goes well but on the next clicks it does not execute the code inside the onclick(). But it still shows the report. It retrieves the data from cache.

```
private class SearchResultFragment extends Fragment {
    private SearchResultFragment(String id, String markupId) {
        super(id, markupId, MemberInformationReportFilterPage.this);

        setOutputMarkupId(true);

        DataView<Member> dataView = new DataView<Member>("dataView", dataProvider) {
            protected void populateItem(Item<Member> item) {
                final MemberModel memberModel = new MemberModel(item.getModelObject());

                Link<Void> link = new Link<Void>("link") {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick() {
                        try {/*method to show the PDF report containing the member's info */
                            reportService.showJasperReport(LocalConstants.REPORT_SOURCE_MEMBERSHIP, getRequestCycle(), getData(memberModel), "member_information.jrxml", getParam(memberModel));
                        } catch (InvalidParameterException|ReportsException e) {
                            setRendered(false);
                            logger.errorException(e.getClass(), e.getMessage());
                            getSession().error(e.getFeedbackMessage());
                        }
                    }
                };
                link.add(new AttributeAppender("target", Model.of("_blank")));

                item.add(link);
```

Getting the data from cache should not be done here since the new updates of the member would not be shown.

Please suggest on what to do to ensure that the system would always execute the onclick code on every user click. Thanks

Comment: Are there any errors (JavaScript or in the server logs) ? Is there an HTTP request for the second click on the link?

Comment: There was no error in JavaScript or in the server logs. Im sorry for being a noob but idk how to check if there was an HTTP request for the second click on the link.

Comment: In the browser's DevTools > Network tab

Comment: Yes there was an HTTP request for the second click. The first and second clicks have the same Request Headers data except for If-Modified-Since.

Comment: It seems Wicket doesn't allow the click for some reason. Can you create a mini application that reproduces the issue and share it somewhere ?

Comment: I'll work on that. Will notify you once it's done. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this solution can fix your problem. But in my case, I have to download a new pdf when executing the onclick function, and I found out that you have to add `.setCacheDuration(Duration.ONE_SECOND)` such that the onclick function will be called in the second time.

```
getRequestCycle().scheduleRequestHandlerAfterCurrent(
    new ResourceStreamRequestHandler(resourceStream)
        .setFileName("my.pdf")
        .setContentDisposition(ContentDisposition.ATTACHMENT)
        .setCacheDuration(Duration.ONE_SECOND)
);
```